# Firestore Full Search Text / Query

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, search

Please somebody could explain the difference between full Search Text (that you need an extra cost to acquire), and Queries in the Firestore Database?.

This means that the only information that I found about queries is outdated, and Full Search Text in Firebase it says that is not supported by Firebase.(https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search?provider=algolia)

I don't understand mainly, why is not supported?, i mean any database should have the option to search words inside their data, so why isn't available in Firebase?

For Aclaration, I want simply to search a specific word in my collections to show the data that matches this search in a table or use this data elsewhere.

Information in general is so inconclusive and vague

Answer (score 1):

If you do a web search for "firestore full text search" you will find lots of prior discussion about this.  Here's one from reddit:

- https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/hqogmz/whats_up_with_fulltext_search_in_firestore_why/?rdt=53627

Here is my response to the question on that thread:

> The reason why Firestore doesn't have full text search is primarily because the performance and infrastructure requirements of Firestore don't match those of text search. Firestore aims to scale massively with no configuration required by the developer. You can easily put billions of documents into a collection, and never have to configure any sort of sharding that would be required to store all that data. Just create your indexes (if necessary), and off you go. These indexes are what make Firestore work well for its intended use cases and scalability requirements.
>
> Any sort of full-featured text search engine would not be able to scale as massively as Firestore using its infrastructure.

In order to understand why full text search isn't supported, you need to understand that [full text search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full-text_search) (please read that to understand what we're talking about) requires far more computing resources than a typical index created for individual fields.  These just don't scale in the way that Firestore guarantees - looking for a word, and variants of the word, and possibly synonyms of that word, ranked by relevancy, is a much more complex (and expensive) problem than finding a single word on its in an index exactly as provided.

It's actually very common for an app to use multiple databases in order to get all the query features required by the app, because different databases are optimized for different types of queries.  Firestore just isn't optimized for full text queries.  There is no one database that's optimized for everything - that is impractical and not cost effective at all.